# Archive old Information in table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to archive old information in my table.

If the value in T1C2 is a number (or less than 5 characters) then I want to replace it with the word **archive** and the value in T1C1.

```
 T1C1  T1C2 

  1     London
  2     New York
  3     2342
  4     Cardiff  
  5     2394
  6     Sydney
  7     2342
  8     2343
  9     7345
```

**Result**

```
  T1C1  T1C2   

  1     London
  2     New York
  3     Archive3
  4     Cardiff  
  5     Archive5
  6     Sydney
  7     Archive7
  8     Archive8
  9     Archive9
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Replacing information with the word 'Archive' is not 'archiving'.

Comment: I want to replace anything numeric with the word archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an update:

```
update mytable
    set t1c2 = 'Archive' + cast(t1c1 as varchar(255))
    where t1c2 not like '%[^0-9]%';
```

You could also use `isnumeric()` for the `where`, but I you need to check for other conditions:

```
where isnumeric(t1c2) = 1 and t1c2 not like '%[.e]%'
```

Comment: Thanks but there is an issue with the SQL as it marks everything as Archive 1.

Comment: @user3191666 . . . It works when I run it in SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71e038/1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET    T1C2 = 'Archive' + Cast(T1C1 AS VARCHAR(100))
WHERE  isnumeric(T1C2) = 1
        OR Len(T1C2) < 5
```

Comment: There is an issue with the SQL as it marks everything as 'Archive1'.

Comment: I think all of your rows contain `1` in `T1C1` column. because I tested it with your data in my `SQL Server 2008` client and it gave expected result. it works fine.